# How to hide a response block in case API doesnot return any value in python

Tags: python, flask

I have Created a Rest API with Flask.I have a response as below ddata

```
data["trafficserver]:{
data["server"]:data["buildnumber"]
}
```

I wanted to hide this in response in case data["trafficServer"] doesnot contain any data.Please help

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Where are you hiding the response - on the client side? What do you mean by does not contain any data? Do you mean the value is null, empty string, or the key "trafficserver" does not exist?

Comment: Yes I mean in the response I am trying to build,  for some case there will not trafficserver data.so I don't want this section will not be returned in response.if data present it will be returned. No null value simply trafficserver is not present for some data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments, you don't want the dictionary key - trafficserver - to be sent back to the client if it has no value.

1. One solution is to look at the components needed to compute the value and if one of them is not present or does not meet the condition for it it to be used, then you don't add the key - trafficserver - to the dictionary

   Example

   ```
   if data.get("buildnumber", None):
       data["trafficserver]= {data["server"]:data["buildnumber"]}
   ```

   This means - only create a value for trafficserver if there is a value for buildnumber
2. Another option is to go through all the keys of the dictionary and drop any key which does not have a value. Something like

   ```
   for k,v in data.items():
       if not v:
           del data[k]
   ```